# Shared file editing issues between Mac OS X Sierra and Windows after Creators Update

Tags: windows, mac, smb

A while ago I updated all the Windows 10 PCs in our office to Creators Update. Let's imagine a situation, where I am accessing a file from Mac OS X Sierra using SMB. I access smb://pcname, mount the drive I want to access and access a .txt file inside the drive. After a few consecutive saves (Ctrl-S) I receive an error inside the OS X which says it cannot save the file. If I try to delete the file, I receive another error, saying the file is in use, even though it is not. Windows 8 or 8.1 PCs don't have the same issue, even though all of the PCs have the WannaCry protection update.I am sure it's not a Sierra issue, because before the Creators Update, everything worked fine.
    Any help debugging the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue went away when I tried to connect to the shared drive from Sierra with cifs://pcname.